# Flexible column width for one specific column

Tags: html, css

I have a table whose cell contents should not wrap on multiple lines.

I want the table to adapt to show the full content of some cells (id, value and actions, in my examples below).

I want the other cell to take the remaining space and to hide the overflow.

Do you think that is possible?

Here's an example fiddle.

- No CSS: Everything wraps on 2 lines which is not ok.
- No Wrap: The table becomes too wide, I want to truncate the description cell.

https://jsfiddle.net/user280767/pfeL3bwk/

```
table.ex-2 td {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

table.ex-2 td.descr {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: are you looking like this? https://jsfiddle.net/pfeL3bwk/1/

Comment: Close to that but I don't want the description to be on multiple lines.  I want it to be truncated (only see the beginning of the text with an ellipsis "...")

Comment: you mean to say you will fix the table width, then the description part will truncate after as much as display in the cell.

Comment: The table should use the space available (100%) and the adjustment of width is only made on the description column.  The other columns should adjust to show the content on one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `table-layout: fixed;`.

See the modified [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/81cak7w4/).

[MDN Article on `table-layout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout).

After you have set fixed width for your table, you can set columns widths, for example, with `col` tag or by setting widths directly to `th`.

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o34seb0f/).

If you want `table` to use all of the width, then just give it `width: 100%;` or leave it default (no rule for width).

Comment: Ok, I tried it and it's not exactly what I want.  With this solution, I have to fix the width of the various columns.  However I don't really know what width they will take, I want it to be set by their content.

Comment: @user280767 Read the article on MDN (link above) or on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp). Then you have got couple of solutions. Run a script that will set the correct width. **Standardize your table** (thanks to that you will actually know what is the maximum width of each column; don't make too general or too perfect styles - it's impossible and it is a bad habit). Or use `flex` instead of table.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments.  I decided to add some javascript (angular directive) to assist me in my goal.